# Showing Exchange Emails in AccountPicker

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to show all the email accounts for an user to pick the desired email. However, Exchange emails are not being shown. Can anyone help me on this?

```
String[] allowableAccountTypes = new String[]{
    GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    GoogleAuthUtil.WORK_ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    "com.outlook.Z7.eas",                // For Exchange accounts
    "com.google.android.legacyimap",
    "com.google.android.gm.legacyimap"};

Intent accountPicker = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, allowableAccountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);

if (accountPicker.resolveActivity(context) != null) { 
    startActivityForResult(accountPicker, ACCOUNT_PICK_RC);
}
```

This shows up all GMail accounts but not the exchange account:

[image]

When trying to go via Add Account root, it doesn't show an option to add an Exchange account:

[image]

Just to reverify, I tried the same in GMail App and here I found Exchange as an option:

[image]

How can achieve showing up Exchange accounts in the list and also let the users able to add an exchange account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason account picker was not showing the exchange account lies in the `allowableAccountTypes`.

Instead of `com.outlook.Z7.eas`, we need to pass `com.google.android.gm.exchange`.

Comment: Where I can find all types of account? thanks